# Substring selection between two Strings

Tags: java, regex, syntax, substring

I'm doing some random Java work, and my app, saves a file with data like:

```
Word: Word1 Description: Desc1 Type: 1 
Word: Word2 Description: Desc2 Type: 2 
Word: Word3 Description: Desc3 Type: 3 
Word: Word4 Description: Desc4 Type: 4
```

It saves it succesfully, when trying to retrieve the data, I'm unable to find out what regex filter I should apply. For example, from line:

```
    Word: Word1 Description: Desc1 Type: 1
```

I'd like to extract:

```
Word1
Desc1
1
```

Each one in different Strings.

I just don't end to understand Patterns syntax, and it's giving me a headhache already. Thanks for your time :)

----------------- EDIT ----------------

Thanks you all! I finally used Kon's answer. The resulting code was much simplier that I thought. I'm leaving the code for anyone who may have a similar problem.

```
package resources;

import resources.manager.Word;

public class CommonFunctions {
public static Word parseString(String str){

    String[] stringA = str.split(" "); 

    Word result = new Word(stringA[1],stringA[3],Integer.parseInt(stringA[5]));
    return result;
}

public static String parseWord(Word wrd){
    //TODO
    return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need and probably shouldn't use regex for this. Use the String.split() method. For example, `String.split(" ")` with a space will return an array where one word is in each element. For example, `String[] array = s.split(" ");`, then you have `array[0] = Word:`, `array[1] = Word1`, etc. Then parsing it is extremely straightforward if your format doesn't change.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are looking for words or numbers that are placed after `:`. You can use this regex `:\\s(\\w+)` which means represents

- `:`
- `\\s*` zero or more whitespace
- `(\\w+)` one or more of characters of type `0-9`, `a-z`, `A-Z` or `_`. Also by surrounding it with parenthesis regex will place this part of match in [group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) 1

Demo:

```
String[] data = { "Word: Word1 Description: Desc1 Type: 1 ",
        "Word: Word2 Description: Desc2 Type: 2 ",
        "Word: Word3 Description: Desc3 Type: 3 ",
        "Word: Word4 Description: Desc4 Type: 4 " };
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(":\\s*(\\w+)");
for (String s:data){
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while (m.find())
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Outpt:

```
Word1
Desc1
1
Word2
Desc2
2
Word3
Desc3
3
Word4
Desc4
4
```

Comment: Good answer.But suggest this :\\s*(\\w+) instead of :\\s(\\w+) which matches zero of more spaces after :

Answer (score 0):

This regex applies to the above data:

`(\b\w+\b)(?!:)`

### What does this regex mean:

1. Begin a capture group `(`

   1. Match a word boundary `\b`
   2. Match alphanumeric characters `\w` between 1 and unlimited times `+`
   3. Match a word boundary `\b`
2. Close the capture group `)`
3. Assert that the following CANNOT be matched starting from this position `(?!` (negative lookahead)

   1. The character `:` literally
4. Close the negative lookahead `)`

Answer (score 0):

### One Liner:

```
String str = "Word: Word1 Description: Desc1 Type: 1";

// Output: ["Word1", "Desc1", "1"]
str.replaceFirst(" ?\\w*: ", "").split(" ?\\w*: ");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use StringTokenizer:

```
String str = "Word: Word1 Description: Desc1 Type: 1";
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str," ");

st.nextToken();
String word = st.nextToken();
St.nextToken();
String description = st.nextToken();
st.nextToken();
String type = st.nextToken();
```

Comment: As it says in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html), StringTokenizer is a legacy class that should not be used in new code.  Additionally, when you use an enumerator-type class like StringTokenizer, you should never call `nextWhatever()` without first calling `hasNextWhatever()` to be sure it won't throw an exception.